# c# VSTO MailItem.Attachments

Tags: c#, vsto

How do I check if MailItem.Attachments already contain attachment with same file path?

Something like

```
if (!MailItem.Attachments.Contains("this"){
  //add it
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attachments collection does not intherit from System.Collections so you can't use typical List methods.  You will have to loop (use a for, not a for each with Outlook objects) through each attachment to evaluate the Attachment.FileName property.

Comment: Thanks, great answer